# Kotlin js/native map object via Types

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to collect some object in a Map, keys are object type (in JVM and kotlin-java it's `Class`). but what can I use for kotlin native and kotlin js codes.

Example Kotlin-JVM code:

```
val pool = HashMap<Class<Any>, Any>>()

val testVal = pool[Test::class.java] as Test
val stringVal = pool[String::class.java] as String

pool[x.javaClass] = x
```

Comment: why not just use `KClass` (i.e. `Test::class` and `String::class`)?

Comment: @msrd0 because KClass also is for JVM reflection. if you try Intellij IDEA auto complete on a Kotlin object (not in jvm platform) there is nothing to do!!

Comment: Oh sorry I thought KClass was available on all platforms